# Error while Generating C/C Header File using "javah" Utility

Tags: android-ndk

**Generating C/C++ Header File using "javah" Utility**

I am following this tutorial
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html

**and to generate Header file i am using following command**

D:\PD\WORKSPACE\AndroidHelloJNIWorkSp\AndroidHelloJNI\bin\classes\com\mytest>javah -classpath ....\bin\classes\com\mytest\JNIActivity.class;D:\PD\NTDK\TDK\android-sdk indows\platforms\android-17\android.jar -o HelloJNI.h com.mytest.JNIActivity

**and i am getting the following error**

Error: Could not find class file for 'com.mytest.JNIActivity'.

please help.

Comment: The `-classpath` argument takes a directory, not a .class file name.

Comment: it still shows the same error with javah -classpath ....\bin\classes\com\mytest\

Answer (score 0):

To generate the header file you need to build the project first. So in Eclipse, goto `Project->Build Project`. Now you will be able to execute the command to build the header file:

```
D:\PD\WORKSPACE\AndroidHelloJNIWorkSp\AndroidHelloJNI\bin\classes\com\mytest>javah -classpath ....\bin\classes\com\mytest\JNIActivity.class;D:\PD\NTDK\TDK\android-sdk indows\platforms\android-17\android.jar -o HelloJNI.h com.mytest.JNIActivity
```